# How to make Extjs not render hidden columns in a grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a grid that has a lot of hidden columns. Only 5 to 10 are visible by default. The users can choose which ever ones they want to view later.

The problem is, even if the column is hidden, Extjs renders the columns. So the page loads and operates very slow.

Is there a way to tell Extjs not to render hidden columns? Only add them to the page when the user decides to view that column? I know there's a column reconfigure or something like that, but I want to allow the user to show/hide the columns using the regular column show/hide menu.

Comment: Only not `hidden` columns are rendered. Don't use width. Check out this: http://jsbin.com/OpuKIKU/2/edit

Comment: Ext 4.2.1 removes the hidden columns from the DOM completely, and as a consequence it doesn't render them (as in squirrel example). Earlier versions render them with a with of 0. Seems like you will have to upgrade!

Comment: Son of a b...not sure if it will be easy for me to upgrade. Last time I tried nothing looked right. Oh well, thanks for the info!